# Webpack add files before compiling through plugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, assets

I am trying to build a webpack plugin and I want to add some files to be processed before the whole compilation step.
My intention is to add some files from a folder to be passed by the normal build process using the desired plugins and loaders.

I realize that if I create a new asset I can do this:

```
  SomePlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
    compiler.plugin("emit", function(compilation, callback) {

      compilation.assets['newAsset.js'] = {
        source: function() {
          return 'content';
        },
        size: function() {
          return 'content'.length;
        }
      };
      callback();
    });
  }
```

But I don't know how to add for example a .scss on the list of files to be processed so webpack can handle the scss file based on the loaders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that using what webpack internally uses can do the trick, suppose you want to add a markdown called test.md to be bundled with the same stuff that you are using, basing it the [EntryOptionPlugin](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/lib/EntryOptionPlugin.js) (What is used to decide how to bundle deppending on the entry options). You can do it like this

```
    MyPlugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {

      compiler.plugin("entry-option", function(context, entry) {
        function itemToPlugin(item, name) {
          if(Array.isArray(item))
            return new MultiEntryPlugin(context, item, name);
          else
            return new SingleEntryPlugin(context, item, name);
        }
        if(typeof entry=== 'string'){
          entry = [entry,__dirname+'/test.md']
        }
        else if (Array.isArray(entry)){
          entry.push(__dirname+'/test.md')
        }
        else{
          entry['SOME_KEY'] = __dirname+'/test.md'
        }
        if( Array.isArray(entry)) {
          compiler.apply(itemToPlugin(entry, "main"));
        } else if(typeof entry === "object") {
          Object.keys(entry).forEach(function(name) {
            compiler.apply(itemToPlugin(entry[name], name));
          });
        }
        return true;
      });
    }
```

The resulting file will be shimmed on your pipeline and handled by the loaders and plugins that you already included.